# Create a function two compare 2 arrays - one with data from csv, one with data from database

Tags: c#, sql, arrays, csv

I am trying to create a function that compares the results of 2 arrays. If they match, then nothing needs to be done. If they do not match, then an UPDATE to a SQL table (called Products_Extension) needs to take place.

Array A is meant to contain the comma-separate list of ItemsAssignedIDs (this field is called uidProducts in the Products_Extension table) for each Product Profile from a .csv file uploaded by the user. Array B is meant to contain a comma-separate list of ItemsAssignedIDs from the database for each Product Profile. Both lists are attached to a Product Profile through the ProfileID field. (I am guessing that I need to clear the items from Array B is A and B don't match, populate Array B with items from Array A, then update the database accordingly)

I have two functions, one that builds a list of ItemsAssignedIDs for each Product Profile in the database, and another that gets all ItemsAssignedIDs from uploaded .csv files. But I am confused on how to combine them so that I can compare the two Arrays.

Function that builds comma-separated list of ItemsAssignedIDs for each Product Profile:

```
private string BuildItemsAssignedList(int ProfileID)
{
    string assignedIdList = "";

    string sqlQuery = "SELECT [uidProducts] FROM Products_Extension WHERE uidProductProfile = @ProfileID";
    using (SqlConnection cn = new SqlConnection(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["AbleCommerce"].ToString()))
    {
        SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(sqlQuery, cn);
        cmd.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@ProfileID", ProfileID));
        cmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
        cn.Open();
        using (IDataReader reader = cmd.ExecuteReader())
        {
            while (reader.Read())
            {
                if (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(assignedIdList))
                    assignedIdList += ", ";
                assignedIdList += (reader["uidProducts"].ToString());
            }
            reader.Close();
        }
        cn.Close();
    }
    return assignedIdList = string.Join(",", assignedIdList);
}
```

Function that splits the comma-separated list of ItemsAssignedIDs from a .csv file for each Product Profile:

```
private void SaveAssignedItems(int ProfileID, string[] row)
{
    string AssignedID = GetValue(row, (int)ProfileColumns.ItemsAssignedIDs);
    AssignedID = AssignedID.ToLower();
    AssignedID.Trim();

    if (AssignedID != "")
    {
        string[] assignedids = AssignedID.Split(',');

        foreach (string item in assignedids)
        {

            int MyVal = Convert.ToInt32(item);
            using (SqlConnection cn = new SqlConnection(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["AbleCommerce"].ToString()))
            {
                SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand();
                cmd.Connection = cn;
                cmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
                cmd.CommandText = "UPDATE Products_Extension SET uidProductProfile = @ProfileID WHERE uidProducts=@AssignedID";
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@ProfileID", ProfileID);
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@AssignedID", item);
                cn.Open();
                cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
                cn.Close();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Why dont you just store both sets into a list instead of concating as strings etc.  If you store both as lists, then its easier to compare List A and B.  Its not the most efficient, but a working solution is always the best first step before optimization.

Comment: What do you mean by storing them?

Comment: hi @SaraDeJaneiro plz make your sentences clear to understand it properly..

Comment: change assignedIdList = List<string> and then change assignedIdList += (reader["uidProducts"].ToString()); to assignedIdList.Add(reader["uidProducts"].ToString();  now that you have a list, you can use things like except to find the differences between another list.

Answer (score 0):

As far as i understood you want to `compare` two `arrays` and perform some operation if matched/don't match right?

Please try the following:

**Method 1**

```
bool found= false;
int[] a = new int[] { 8, 1, 2, 3, 4 };
int[] b = new int[] { 5, 6, 7, 8 };
foreach (var numberA in a)
{
    foreach (var numberB in b)
    {
        if (numberA == numberB)
        {
            found= true;
        }

    }
    if(!found)
    {
          //numberA not found in array B
    }
}
```

**Mehtod 2:**

```
 int[] a = new int[] { 1, 2, 3, 4 };
 int[] b = new int[] { 1, 2, 3 };
 var result = a.Except(b).ToArray();
 foreach (var item in result)
 {
    Response.Write("\nItems not in B are :"+item);
 }
```

**NOTE:** Please do not use 'as is'. make changes accordingly..!

Comment: you can do this easier as var diff = a.Except(b); rather than all the looping.

Comment: hi @KevinCook i have updated my answer according to your suggestion :)

Comment: var result is already an enumerable so you can drop the ToArray() as well, you will still be able to foreach(int item in result) without it.